# Defining dynamic limit for a list plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, manipulate

Helly everybody,

I will try to keep this as simple as possible.

1. I have a **function** which looks like this:

   ```
   Min[T_, E_, D_] := Module[ ..... List = {...} ];
   ```

In any case this function gives me a list that looks like this `{1,2, 1, 4,5, 2,1}` etc. (Actually `D` determines the number of entries in this list)

2. I use **Listplot** to plot this list.

   ```
   ListPlot[Min[T, E, D], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0,  0.5}}]
   ```
3. I use `Manipulate` to be able to manipulate any of these 3 Variables.

   ```
   Manipulate[ListPlot[Min[...], {T, 1, 20}, {D, 10, 20}, {E, 1, 20}]
   ```

   Everything worked perfectly and dandy, but I ran into one problem. `E` has a dynamic limit that changes when I change `D` or `T` and few other factors.
4. So in order to be able to calculate the dynamic limit of`E`, I had to write a few new lines in the old `Min`.

   So now it looks something like this:

   ```
   Min[T_, E_, D_] := 
     Module[Emax = T + D  + a; List = {...}];
   ```

   where `a` is a variable only used in that function

Even though `Emax` is getting calculated correctly, I just cannot use it outside of the function.

When I plug it into the `Manipulate` stuff like this:

```
ListPlot[Min[...], {T, 1, 20}, {D, 10, 20}, {E, 1, Emax}]
```

the code does not know what `Emax` is.

Any ideas what I can do?

I need to use a variable from inside a function as limit for a `Manipulate`.

Comment: `Min`, `List`, `N`, `D` and `E` are built-in and (mostly) protected symbols. Can you prepare a small working example which shows the problem? It is not clear if mentioned symbols are the problem or the exact syntax you use (which is not shown either).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Manipulate[emax = Quotient[max, 3]; ListPlot[Prime[Range[emax]]], {max, 10, 20}]
```

Manipulate allows ; separated statements before the one that produces the output and treats all the variables as dynamic

Comment: This worked quite welll. But sadly not as good as I have wished.

I was able to determine the Variable with the desired value just as  you said, in a seperate statement before the one that produces the output.

Let's call this Variable A. Now I'm in an odd situation where I used A for 2 things:

Comment: 1. I used it as Epiloge to be displayed next to the Plot so I can see how it changes.



Epilog -> {  Text[Style[A "A", ...]};




2. I used it as a Limit for the Manipulate of one of the Variables. 

Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {Automatic...}, {D, 1, A}];



It works for the Epiloge. But it does not work for the limit. As I change the other 2 variables I see A changing on the Epilogue but the Limit for Variable D stays constant. Why ? I was hoping that it would update the Value for the Limit aswell :/